# Windows 10 taskbar icon changes when pinned

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I'm using an application called Talend Open Studio for Data Integration, and when I open it this is what the taskbar icon looks like:

[image]

As you can see there appears to be some white borders that probably aren't supposed to be there. However when I *pin* it to the taskbar, this is what it looks like:

[image]

So my question is why does this happen? And is there a way to get rid of the white borders without pinning the program?

Comment: Next time you post two (or more) similar images for comparison, please crop them the same.

Comment: The images you uploaded seem alike. I cannot figure out the differences. Could you give more info?

Comment: The first image has a thin white border around the outside.